# Check for null Component in Java Swing Panel

Tags: java, swing, components

I am creating dynamic buttons and dynamic button handlers inside of a JPanel, and thus am selecting them again using the "Panel.getComponentAt(x, y)" method.

This method can obviously select from an area that has nothing in it, and this would return a null pointer exception as expected.

I need a way to check whether or not it is selecting an actual component so it does not throw the error, should I just use a try and catch block here? or is there something more elegant? I have tried "isValid()" on a whim, and this doesn't not seem to be what I'm looking for.

Many Thanks

Comment: `getComponentAt` does not throw a `NullPointerException` itself. It just returns `null`. That's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentAt%28int,%20int%29) for `Container#getComponentAt()`

> null if the component does not contain the position. If there is no
>   child component at the requested point and the point is within the
>   bounds of the container the container itself is returned; otherwise
>   the top-most child is returned.

so you can do

```
Component c = Panel1.getComponentAt(x, y);

if ( c!= null && c != Panel1)
{
   // a child component was found
   ...
}
```

Comment: `Panel1` should be replaced by `panel1`